# SwiftUI Pass a String as an argument in a function called in a different view

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, function, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class RepliesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var noRgrt = [NoRgrt]()
    
    init() {
        fetchNoRgrtReplies()
    }

    
    func fetchNoRgrtReplies(noRgrt: String? = nil) {
        let query = COLLECTION_NORGRTS.document(noRgrt ?? "jGRDaEOKz137s8ewdCCx").collection("noRgrt-replies")
            .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
        
        query.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.noRgrt = documents.map({ NoRgrt(dictionary: $0.data()) })
        }
    }
    
}
```

I want the function to take a string as a parameter and call it in a separate view. I'm using the id `jGRDaEOKz137s8ewdCCx` as a placeholder.

I'm trying to call it here but I am unsure how to use the String of `noRgrt.id` which is a String. Im getting the following error... `Cannot call value of non-function type '[NoRgrt]'`

```
ScrollView() {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(repliesViewModel.noRgrt(noRgrt.id)) { noRgrt in
                        NoRgrtCell(noRgrt: noRgrt)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have a Constant `let noRgrt = NoRgrt` which is the Struct/Model that contains `.id`.

How can I call `repliesViewModel.noRgrt` with the string of `noRgrt.id` in the view

Comment: getDocuments Is asynchronous, so you can’t call the function and expect the results to be immediately available. Instead, call it in onAppear and then just display the results in the ForEach (or conditionally display a loading indicator or something until the array has content)

Comment: "...How can I call `repliesViewModel.noRgrt` with the string of `noRgrt.id` in the view...".
`repliesViewModel.noRgrt` is an array of `NoRgrt`, an array takes an integer index in square brackets, to 
retrieve a specific element, such as `repliesViewModel.noRgrt[0]`. If you know that your 
`noRgrt.id` can translate into a valid index, then use:  `repliesViewModel.noRgrt[noRgrt.id]`.
However I would recommend you change your code structure and avoid doing that.

Comment: [noRgrt.id] is giving me error... Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'...   Would that be the case if my id is initialized as such, ```init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""```

Comment: You mentioned it would be best to change structure, can you point me in the right direction? What part should I change?

Comment: have a look at this doc: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html
and this: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array 
to understand arrays.

Comment: there is not enough info and code to advice on how to restructure your code.
Re-read the basic tutorials and how to use `ObservableObject`

Comment: Ok so I was able to get my replies into an array contained in each post. Now I just have to figure out how to display them from the array. Thank you!